# Wireless Adapter + Arduino 'Bug'

Tags: network, attacks, hardware, wireless, router

First, I am new to ethical hacking. And also I just realized that I need a wireless adapter for wireless attacks. I'm currently mastering Python, and some basic knowledge in Bash and Arduino.

### **What I Need**

I need a sort of 'bug' or gadget to connect to via wireless adapter and can be placed and hidden it somewhere, or at least to get some distance from my target (for now let's just say my friend's house). Or maybe (if possible) make a fake Wi-Fi Router with a fake SSID. With this, I can monitor and scan and possibly hack the network around the bug/gadget. This gadget should be small enough so I'm thinking using a Wi-Fi Adapter and Arduino + Wi-Fi Shield or 2 Wi-Fi Adapter and Arduino with some sort of Battery or solar panel.

### The Question

Maybe a visualization will help understanding of my idea:

```
-------   _
|  a  |~~/b\~~>to c        -some distance-                   _
|     |                                           from b ~~>/c\
-------

where:
a. Target's House        |   ~~> or ~~ : connected wirelessly 
b. The Bug or Gadget     |
c. My Laptop             |
```

1. Is this possible?
2. Does this thing already exist? This is maybe
   because I'm new and don't know.
3. How should this be working?
4. What do I need?

Comment: For most ethical hacking, you'd just sit in your target's office, and see what was available. The exception would be when performing "red team" or other "simulated attack" testing, in which case, a mobile phone would seem to be a pretty simple device to use for this - got WiFi, got remote connection, got battery, doesn't look suspicious if found...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are thinking of Arduino + bits, I'd recommend using an ESP8266. These are just a few dollars and come with Wi-Fi and an embedded microprocessor similar to an Arduino.

Wemos do a small fully configured ESP8266 device and a battery charge/use addon that will support LIPO batteries.

However, those might be rather restrictive in terms of what you can run on them in order to run Wi-Fi audits.

So probably better would be an SBC - Single Board Computer. Raspberry Pi's are possibly the most famous and the cheapest of those is only around $10. But there are many more. You would need to add battery and Wi-Fi (some SBC's come with that built in) and an SD card. They typically run Linux though a Pi will run Windows 10 Core if you like :-)

You would still need to get/write some software but as you are running a fairly standard OS, you can run standard network scanning/auditing tools and the like.

Comment: is 'wifi audit' is the name for what i meant ?
aaah RasPi's ! is it possible to have 2 wireless adaptor linked each other and one of them to connect to me an the other to target's device ?

Comment: Wi-Fi Audit is certainly one of the names used for this kind of thing, yes. Yes, you can run 2 adapters - you will need to create a route between them though otherwise they are treated separately. There are lots of posts about creating a router/firewall using Linux and you should be able to adapt one of them.

Comment: the ESP8266 can run Arduino code and would be MUCH better on batteries than a PI. Using AP+STA mode, you can both scan and host a "hotspot" that you can connect to to fetch data. The ESP's Arduino WiFi lib is pretty comprehensive, and should let you accomplish such tasks quite simply. With power management, you can run an ESP for months on batteries.

Comment: Well it would be an interesting challenge trying to do a Wi-Fi audit from an ESP8266 with its very limited memory and processing capability. And **much** easier on a SBC. Battery power not likely to be an issue as you would need something decent even with the ESP given the time required to run an audit. A USB power bank would take care of that either way - really not an issue.